# how can we process,draggable directions coordinates to gpx file for gps device

Tags: google-maps-api-3

how can we process draggable directions coordinates(google map api v3) to gpx file for gps device..

Any one knows,explain as detail.. please help and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The following answer help to show gpx file in google map ..(75% suitable for above question)

The following snippet assumes that a map has been created, and is referenced by the map variable (of type google.maps.Map). After the track has been added to the map, the last instruction zooms to fit the track.

```
    $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "URL to the GPX file",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
    var points = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
    $(xml).find("trkpt").each(function() {
      var lat = $(this).attr("lat");
      var lon = $(this).attr("lon");
      var p = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
      points.push(p);
      bounds.extend(p);
    });

    var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
      // use your own style here
      path: points,
      strokeColor: "#FF00AA",
      strokeOpacity: .7,
      strokeWeight: 4
    });

    poly.setMap(map);

    // fit bounds to track
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
});
```

The code works as follows. Retrieve the GPX file using an XMLHttpRequest (“AJAX” request). jQuery parses the file and provides very easy access to the XML tree. For each trkpt (“track point”) node, create a new Google Maps point at the given location. Finally, create a polyline from all these points, and add it to the map.